# Replacing caption between <a> with attributes

Tags: hyperlink, preg-replace

I'm trying to preg_replace a link caption as below. Can't find an example tho where replacing would consider tag attributes, not just clean tags

Basically, this

```
  <a href="/some/address" class="active">Database Title</a>
```

needs to become this

```
  <a href="/some/address" class="active">My Own Title</a>
```

Help appreciated

Comment: see  this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp

Comment: thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can a use a regular expression along with back references

```
$html = '<a href="/some/address" class="active">Database Title</a>;
$html = preg_replace("/(<.+>).+(<.+>)/", "$1My Own Title$2", $html);

echo $html;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php